# SQL Process without Task State bocks other processes

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-business-central

I'm having an issue with processes that lock my SQL Server even though they appear to be finished.
[image: Activity Monitor Screenshot]

The blocking Processes are 4 a simple `SELECT GETDATE()` commands that just don't finish for some reason unknown to me. The SQL Server Profiler doesn't really show any activity except for repeating the `SELECT GETDATE()` every four minutes. - It is possible that the same connection sent a UPDLOCK request before that.

I mostly want to find an explaination for that behaviour. I can't really influence those blocking requests. - As you can see, they are sent by an external company.

The suspended process is also called from within the Business Central Server, but is circumventing the standard interpretation layer to optimize performance. - To do this, it's calling the SQL .Net Class to execute the SQL query directly.

If i kill the process, the server throws an error and the whole execution falls appart.

p.s. for the PPL that work with BC in here and think this is not a good idea:
This code won't run on a daily business. I it's just for migrating data during upgrades from NAV to BC. We Build a tool that allows us to map Fields between C/AL and AL solutions and generate AL-Extension based on those mappings. These extensions grab the data from a copy of the original DB and write them directly into their destination files. We need the SQL commands because some of our customers have so much data accumulated over the years that an upgrade would otherwise take more than a Week if the data was processed in AL

Comment: Have you tried profiling it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15 ?

Comment: @AlexanderToptygin I have to admit i didn't have time to wait any longer so i circumvented the problem by changing the order of execution until the lock didn't happen anymore - not a very satisfying solution as i prefer resolving issues to circumventing them.